# Z-test with large sample sizes but small proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, proportion, z-test

I'm running an A/B test to determine if a change/treatment we're proposing for our website has an impact on users opting into a specific (niche) category of notifications.

To do so, I'm performing a one-tailed z test of two independent proportions (treatment vs control). However, I'm concerned with the results of my test because of how small the proportions are despite having large samples sizes. Here's my situation:

**Control group:**

- User count: 108,807
- Users opting into notifications: 6
- Proportion: 0.0000551435

**Treatment group:**

- User count: 108,480
- Users opting into notifications: 16
- Proportion: 0.000147493

**Z test results:**

- My results show a p-value of 0.016211, which would be statistically significant given our confidence level of 95%.

**My questions:**

1. Are my current results valid?
2. Is using a z test correct in this situation, or is there a more appropriate test (e.g. Fisher's exact)?

It's worth noting that there are multiple other metrics I'm hoping to track during A/B tests where proportions are similarly very small while samples sizes are quite large.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: FYI, user assignments for the two groups are randomized.

Comment: I would guess you are reporting a one-tailed p-value; if so, the correct p-value is twice that, or 0.032.  Assuming you randomized people into the two groups, this is close to the exact hypergeometric p-value of 0.052 associated with 6 out of 6 + 16 = 22 people being placed into one of the groups and the other 16 into the other group--but the difference does take you under your threshold of 95% confidence.

Comment: @whuber - Honest question... Wouldn't I want to perform a one-tailed test, with my alternative hypothesis being treatment proportion > control proportion?

Comment: That presumes you're absolutely certain the treatment will improve things--or at least won't make them any worse. That's a dangerous form of statistical hubris, so the general recommendation is to use two-tailed tests to protect you from it.

Comment: With very large n and very small p=K/n you're dealing with approximately Poisson variates for the count (the hypergeometric will be well approximated by a Poisson in that situation); this provides a useful way to judge how well a normal approximation for the difference might work; if you have a sense of the typical ballpark of the expected counts, those will tend to give a reasonable way to judge, though really seeing when it's suitable also depends on how far into the tail you need with how much accuracy.